# C#/Dapper executing stored procedure with table-valued parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper, sqlclient

I have an object in my SQL Server database that is called `dbo.stringlist`

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[StringList] AS TABLE
                                  (
                                      [Item1] [varchar](2000) NULL
                                  )
```

I have a stored procedure that has syntax in SSMS like

```
exec [dbo].[Getdata] @Fields
```

(which is the `dbo.stringlist`) which effectively just joins on a table in the stored procedure and acts as a long list of criteria. It's how I want to deal with the request on the database side, so I won't be changing that.

All I want to do is execute this in C# (hopefully) using Dapper, because the rest of the goal has been built out using nothing but Dapper. I can scrap it if need be. The goal is to effectively write an ETL of sorts, but instead of endpoint-to-endpoint SSIS-like packages, I am just automating deploy scripts for new builds.

If there is a way to do this outside of Dapper that is easier, then I am all for scrapping this at this point. Like I said, the documentation for this is sparse, at least the updated documentation for this specific task is sparse.

I tried this method - https://gist.github.com/taylorkj/9012616

And also tried this method - https://bornsql.ca/blog/table-valued-parameters-and-dapper-in-net-core/

The second one didn't work, because I just want to pass the list in, but that's not an option. It needs to be an `IEnumerable`, which I don't feel like I can pass values into like a list. But maybe I just don't know what I am doing when it comes to that interface.

So if anyone has an UP-TO-Date link to help me out that would be stellar. I have a feeling I am going to have to scrap everything I have done, which is fine, I guess. I just want the tool to work. I know this post doesn't have a lot of information, that's why I am just asking for ideas to accomplish what I am trying to do in C# and hopefully Dapper, but like I said, I am not married to it.

Comment: Side note: if you can, give your table type a primary key. For example `Item1 varchar(2000) PRIMARY KEY`

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with the second link.

```
private static IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> CreateSqlDataRecord(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    var metaData = new SqlMetaData("Item1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2000);
    var record = new SqlDataRecord(metaData);
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        record.SetSqlString(0, item);
        yield return record;
    }
}

public static SqlMapper.ICustomQueryParameter GetTableValuedParameter()
{

    string[] list = new string[] { };

    return CreateSqlDataRecord(list).AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.StringList");
}
```

I wasn't updating the parameter nor was I including a varchar data length of 255.